# Setting decoded JSON data to UITextFields in Swift - issues with non-strings

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have decoded some JSON data into an array in one of my view controllers. Here's what the struct looks like for my JSON data:

```
struct Country: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var country: String
    var capital: String
    var nationalLanguage: [String]
    var population: Int
}
```

I'm passing in all of the data for a selected row in a tableView to a property of type Country in a separate view controller. I've commented on the lines where there is an error.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var idTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var capitalTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var languageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var populationTextField: UITextField!
    
    var countryItem: Country?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        idTextField.text = countryItem?.id // Error
        nameTextField.text = countryItem?.country
        capitalTextField.text = countryItem?.capital
        languageTextField.text = countryItem?.nationalLanguage // Error
        populationTextField.text = countryItem?.population // Error
        
    }
}
```

The error reads:

```
Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context
```

I know it's because those three data types are not of type string, but I'm not sure what I need to do to fix that. Typecasting them as strings does not work and gives me the following error:

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Int?' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set an Int/array to a string `text`  value of  `UITextField` You need

```
if let res = countryItem {
   idTextField.text = String(res.id) // Error Int set to String
   nameTextField.text = res.country
   capitalTextField.text = res.capital
   languageTextField.text = res.nationalLanguage.first // Error Array to String
   populationTextField.text = String(res.population) // Error Int set to String
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was an easier solution than I'd thought. Thank you! Could you explain why that behaves like that? Is it because my Country struct was an optional and I needed to unwrap it?